# Where can I find historical (very old) USD printing data?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, currency, data-request

Where can I find historical/very old USD printing data? Charts can be useful, but I want numbers. It is for a project.

Comment: You want tabular historical data on the composition of the US currency supply?

Comment: Yes. I want the amount of dollars printed yearly.

Comment: To be more precise: do you want the aggregate dollar amount, or a decomposition by bills (\$1 bills, \$5, \$20, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bureau of Engraving and Printing maintains [public records on their web site](http://www.moneyfactory.gov/resources/productionannual.html), but that data only goes back to 1980. Therefor your best option might be to [write or call them](http://www.moneyfactory.gov/contactus.html) and ask for information for the time period you're interested in. If they are not forthcoming, you can call back and try your luck with a different staff member. If that doesn't work, you can resort of filing a [Freedom of Information Act request](https://www.moneyfactory.gov/foia.html). According to [this page](https://foiamapper.com/agencies/treasury-foia/treasury-bep-foia/) the average turnaround time is 23-31 days depending on the complexity of the request.

There is also [this site](https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/money-supply-m0), which has information on the US money supply from 1959 - present, but I am not sure it is presented in a way you'll find useful for your project. I am also unsure if it meets your definition of "very old."

Good luck!